# Android app freezing when calling ArrayList.set

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

In my Android project, I'm making a small list with an
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.
I would like to make the list editable and where we could change any HashMap item within the ArrayList. But when I call `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.set(pos, myHashMap);`, (assuming the ArrayList already has the items etc) the app totally freezes. Nothing is printed in the logcat. Nothing happens. The ripple effect of the button to edit the list just keep being checked.
What may I do wrong?

Comment: What is the call to `set` inside of? Are you using any frameworks? It sounds like an exception is being swallowed by something.

Comment: I have basically a dialog with the inputs and a button, where you can change the inputs and when you are satisfied with them, you click on the button to edit the list. I don't use anything else...